# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke correct usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, begininvoke

I am working on understanding how to use BeginInvoke correctly.  I wrote up a small test in a console app where all I am trying to do is use BeginInvoke to call a function to make a 100x100 Window with a title pop up.  I am failing miserably.  Here is what I have, I know this is probably just poor understanding of Threads (not my strong suit), but I'm stuck, no window pops up I just end up at my readline in Main waiting for a keypress.  Execution starts at ThreadUITest.

```
static void ThreadUITest()
{
    ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(threadFunc1);
    Thread test = new Thread(starter);
    test.IsBackground = true;
    test.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    test.Start();
}

static void threadFunc1()
{
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; //Statically declared earlier
    ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(threadFunc2);
    Thread test = new Thread(starter);
    test.IsBackground = true;
    test.Start();
}

static void threadFunc2()
{
    Action method = Draw;
    Console.WriteLine("I'm here!");
    //dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action)(() => {Draw();}),DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method, DispatcherPriority.Send, null);
 }

 static void Draw()
 {
     Window win = new Window();
     win.Height = 100;
     win.Width = 100;
     win.Title = "A Window!";
     win.Show();
 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it work when you use `dispatcher.Invoke`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `Dispatcher.Run()` in the end of `threadFunc1`.

Comment: Ok.  That did it.  Doesn't a new Dispatcher get created with the Thread? and if so, why wouldn't the silly thing just run?

Comment: @AaronMarcus Creating a thread does not automatically create a message loop, no.  Most threads won't have message loops in them.  That said, your program has much bigger design problems that are not solved by simply adding this one line.

Comment: I think the logic is that constructors and properties shouldn't block. So `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` doesn't start the loop when it creates the dispatcher. But yes, it seems strange that `Invoke` doesn't start it.

Comment: I'm aware this is *NOT* well designed code.  Again, I was shooting for a quick and dirty test of BeginInvoke to fiddle with it a little bit before I start running around I assuming I knew how it was working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following at the bottom of your `threadFunc1`

```
// statically declared earlier, although you don't need to keep a reference to it as 
// WPF will keep it in Application.Current
application = new Application(); 
application.Run(); // thread1 is now our "UI" thread
```

Why does this solve it?

The `Dispatcher` object provides an interface for getting a thread to do some work for you (via `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke`).
In order for a thread to be able to process any "do work" messages, it must be running some kind of event loop, where it sits and waits for the next message to process - if it weren't doing this, then it wouldn't be able to process anything, it would just be stuck.

Calling `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from thread1 will create a new dispatcher on that thread if there isn't one already there[1] - that gives us our interface to post messages to the thread.
What `dispatcher.BeginInvoke` does is add an entry into the message queue for that thread, however the thread isn't running any message loop yet. We can queue messages to it, but it won't pick them up and run them - this is why nothing happens.

So, we need to make that thread start running a message loop.
The `Application.Run()` method is the WPF framework method which does exactly that. The `Application.Run` method never returns (until you call `Application.Shutdown` anyway), it starts up a message loop to begin processing messages thereafter. I find it useful to think of it "taking over" the thread.

Now with this change, when thread2func calls `dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, the message loop code inside `Application.Run` goes "oh look, a message, I'll process it" - it gets the `BeginInvoke` method, and does what it's told (in this case, executing your `Draw` function), and all is well

---

Note: As per [Ark-kun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20980292/234) You can also just call `Dispatcher.Run` to start a message loop on that thread without creating an Application object (Application.Run does this internally). Generally I find it nicer to create an application object though, as that's more "normal", and some other code you may write later on may expect an Application object to exist

---

[1] FYI, this is why calling `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is dangerous and you should avoid it. If you call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the existing UI thread, it returns you a reference to the correct dispatcher.
If you accidentally call it from another thread, logically, you'd think it would return a reference to the existing dispatcher. But no - instead, it creates a **second** dispatcher, pointing at our other thread - however our other thread won't be running a message loop, and we'll get stuck again. I'd suggest never calling `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` except for the very first time.

Once your app is up and running, you generally don't need to do this anyway, as all WPF objects (Window, Button, etc) all have a `Dispatcher` property which you can use to get the correct dispatcher from anyway

Comment: `Dispatcher` is about processing abstract events. It's not very `WPF`-specific and is located in `WindowsBase.dll`. `Application` is located in `PresentationFramework.dll` and is about `Windows`, `Resources` and navigation. Depending on the situation, one might prefer the minimalistic `Dispatcher` instead of the full-blown `Application`.

Comment: This is a little over-complexifying the situation because this was a test framework just to fiddle about with BeginInvoke to make sure I was using it correctly, so I didn't care about full blown Applications, thank you for the additional info though!